# Removing the last slash of URL in XAMPP

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, xampp, trailing-slash

I am currently working a project with PHP and Apache on a local server using XAMPP. I have an issue on my website, I was wondering if I can delete the last slash of my web URL. For example, I'm running a website in `localhost` and it was stored in folder `htacces\web\mywebsite` and when I open the website in the browser, the URL bar shows `localhost/web/mywebsite/` or `127.0.0.1/web/mywebsite/`.

So if this is normal then it's fine, but why can some site like `stackoverflow.com` remove the last slashes, also like `stackoverflow.com\question\ask`?

I just want to know about that, is `.htaccess` will do? or PHP?
here is the .htacces file that I have written in my website

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [QSA]
```

Could anyone help?

Comment: `question/ask` is not a real directory but `web/mywebsite` is. Apache adds a  trailing slash in front of directories for security reasons.

Comment: Are you using a Framework. I guess not, so you need to handle routing

Comment: @anubhava so even `web/mywebsite/something` will have a trailling slash too?

Comment: @menaka yes i'm not, so to remove the trailling slash i need to handle the routing?

Comment: alright, but when i visit `web/mywebsite/login` which not a directory, but the trailling is still there, can you explain why?

Comment: No, I cannot explain as that is your system not mine :). Enable `RewriteLog` and find out where is trailing slash coming from.

Comment: or maybe cause this line of code `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [QSA]` or something?

Comment: Yeah you right, i need to figure it out by myself, i will try to `log` it

Answer (score 1):

the slash on the end doesnt make much difference. So you just could ignore it, but if you want to allow opening the directories without slash you cant do that in the .htaccess file i think.